# Intersecting Volume in Matlab

Tags: matlab, 3d, volume, intersection, delaunay

I have developed a code that takes a set of 3D coords, and performs triangulation to generate the convex hull/Delaunay .

This has gone well and using the Deluanay triangulation I can test whether points are contained in a given volume using tsearchn.

Now I want to take two of such 3D volumes, and test whether they intersect.
Futhermore I would like to know what the percentage of volume A is intersected by Volume B.

I think that I could generate a mesh grid of points that are within one of the volumes, then test them into the other using tsearchn. But I wanted to know if anyone knows of more convenient way. Or has advice for doing similar analyses.

Many Thanks!

#### EDIT ... Example Code

For this sample code, `shapeA` would be 50% intersected by `shapeB`.
I included a section at the end of the code that shows the usability of `tsearchn`
I know that I could solve my problem by increasing the number of points for the shapes  and testing them using `tsearchn`

```
% Establish shapes by coordinates
botA = [ 0 0 0 ; ...
   1 0 0;  ...
   1 1 0;  ...
   0 1 0 ];

topA = botA; topA(:,3) = 1; 
midA = [0.5 0.5 0.5];

botB = [ 0 0 0.5 ; ...
   1 0 0.5;  ...
   1 1 0.5;  ...
   0 1 0.5 ];

topB = botA; topB(:,3) = 1.5; 
midB = [0.5 0.5 1];

% Shape arrays
shapeA = [botA;midA;topA];
shapeB = [botB;midB;topB];

% Establish volume by using the delaunayn() function
dtA = delaunayn(shapeA);
dtB = delaunayn(shapeB);

% Plot the volume surfaces 
shapesurfA=tetramesh(dtA,shapeA);
set(shapesurfA,'FaceColor','b','FaceAlpha',.90,'EdgeAlpha',1);

hold on
shapesurfB=tetramesh(dtB,shapeB);
set(shapesurfB,'FaceColor','y','FaceAlpha',.90,'EdgeAlpha',1);
hold off
axis equal

%example of point in volume test
%if tsearchn output = NaN then testpoint is not in volume
testpoint1 = tsearchn(shapeA,dtA, [ 2 2 2]) % [test point [2 2 2] in volume A
testpoint2 = tsearchn(shapeA,dtA, [0.75 0.75 0.75])
```

Comment: So, given two volumes defined by 4 points in 3-space, you want to know if the two tetrahedrons defined intersect?  Or if the two spheres defined intersect?

Comment: Please see example code for a more specific demonstration of the problem. And my current solution and my expected result